# Entity framework 4, update specific properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm used to using code first where I can do:

```
db.Users.Attach(user);
db.Entry(user).Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;
```

How do I do this with a DataModel approach?

I do not have the `Entry` method on my datacontext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
context.Users.Attach(user);
ObjectStateEntry entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user);
entry.SetModifiedProperty(propertyName);
```